# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code with Alamofire

Tags: xcode, code-signing

[image]

The photo explains itself
I'm getting this error when trying to build my project
Tried to:

- Delete Derived Data
- pod install/update/deintegrate
- Restarting xCode
- Cleanin the project
- Even restarting my Mac and trying to build the same project on a different machine

Comment: UPD: It seems to happen with even when i install only 1 pod

Comment: I am facing the same issue. You got solution for this issue?

Comment: @Manigandasaravanan
The problem could be with the Swift/CocoaPods version
Try on a newer or older version, then 'pod deintegrate' and 'pod install'

Answer (score 2):

My friend, I had the exact same issue, and here is the cause and resolution:

[image]

Your project's name using the sign: ( ' ) => when the pod reconfig the project name => some directory missed this sign, but somewhere not => error: "No such file or directory"

Resolution: rename your project to the format: MyNewProjectName

Comment: Had the similar issue, when updating XCode to version 12.0, the only difference is that my path had space (i.e "a/XCode Projects/b"), for some reason XCode 12 didn't like that. (XCode 11 builded same project correctly)

Answer (score 0):

May be this issue is related to keychain access. I fixed this issue by performing following steps:

```
Open Keychain Access
Lock and Unlock the login keychain
Clean and build Xcode app
```